# Should I get a lawyer after my accident?

Tags: texas, insurance

Last Tuesday I got in an accident with a lady who is insured with GEICO. I merged into the middle lane (three lane highway in TX) I was in the lane and all of a sudden this lady who was in my left lane decided she needed to take the next right like RIGHT NOW. hit my car and caused me to hit the divider and busted front tires.

My driver and passenger door were smashed, my headlights smashed, my wheel axles and shocks broke and I had to tow my car. Police came, asked me what happened, than asked the lady and asked if we were okay. No citations were issued to me.

Now my car is an old Chevy Impala and not really worth fixing the body damage and don't really care how it looks so long as it drives. Her insurance told me they would deny my claim and to give them couple of days to get everything sorted out. So today, I get my class from my insurance saying the lady who hit me got a lawyer! Now I'm freaking out! Since the police didn't say who was at fault and both insurance companies deny the claim, who will the lawyer go after? A broke college student? Someone help me!

Comment: Is your question really "who will the lawyer go after?"? If she hired the lawyer, the lawyer is going after you and your insurance, of course. What you need to do is get a copy of the police report, give it to your insurance. Your insurance should be going to bat for you. Why else would you have been paying them all these years? Does the police report state who the police determined was as fault? It could be percentages, you may be 30% at fault, and the lady may be 70% at fault, or vice versa.

Comment: I absolutely agree with @mikeazo - Your insurance company is there to INSURE you - while the other party may go after you, they are, correctly, doing it through your insurance company  and your insurance company should handle this all for you - thats what you pay them for.  No need to freek out - if you have any questions - call your insurance company and ask them - they should have no problems explaining the process as they do it day-in and day-out.

Comment: Police report states that it was not possible to determine who was at fault. My insurance denied her claim and her insurance denied mine! I did send my insurance company the police report. To me the car isn't worth all the hassle. It did sustain significant body damage but it's an old 2006 Impala. I'm just scared about the lawyer thing since I did not hire one.

Comment: What is your insurance recommending you do? Likely either she or her insurance looked at the police report and felt like they could make a case that it was your fault, and are therefore suing your insurance to get them to cover the claim. If that is the case, then your insurance would have to look at the evidence and decide what they want to do. Do they just cover the claim? Do they let it play out in court? Do they counter-sue? The worst thing you can do right now is panic. The best thing you can do right now is keep in touch with your insurance.

Comment: What do you mean when you write, "I get my class from my insurance saying...?"

Answer (score 2):

Based on your [other question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11686/car-insurance-claim-was-denied-what-are-my-options) (which is not all that well distinguished from this one), if you want to sue the other party for the damages to your car you would probably need a lawyer for that, though it'd be expensive.

If the other lady is going to sue you for the damages to her car, she (via her lawyer) would serve you with formal papers for a lawsuit.  At that time, you'd call up your insurance company and they should send an attorney to defend the case for you because you have liability coverage.  If the other lady, after consulting with her attorney, decides not to sue you (e.g. observing how expensive that attorneys' fees would likely be for a full suit), you might just not hear anything more.